# how to display TabView on top of page on iOS

Tags: nativescript

i'm using *[Tab View](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view)* and I'd like to show Tabs on top of pages on *iOS* devices. In *nativescript document* has written that

> The iOS tabs have their tab bar, which will be displayed always on the bottom and does not allow swipe gesture for changing tabs.

[image]

But I'd like to know is there a way to show tabs on top on iOS Devices like android?

Any Idea?

Comment: With native elements you are stucked with bottom, only way how to do it is with some custom written logic/views but not sure how complicated it can be. And not best practise to keep android and ios to totally same look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design iOS doesn't support that, there is a open [feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3871) too.

The workaround is to hide the tabbar and use a GridLayout to place a tabbar like buttons above and select appreciate tab upon tapping them.